# Issues with scala-parser-combinators: parsing text of the form `(typ1: value1) (type2: value2) ... `

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I want to parse text of the following form:

```
"(typ1: value1) (type2: value2) (type3: value3)"
```

Here is my code:

```
  case class Word(word: String) extends Expression
  case class Cluster(wrapped: Expression) extends Expression

  def parse(input: String): ParseResult[Expression] = {
    val expressions = "(" ~> expr <~ ")" ^^ {expr => Cluster(expr) }
    val capture3 = expressions ~> ":" ^^ Word
    def expr: Parser[Expression] = rep1(expressions) ^^ { exprs =>
        if (exprs.size > 1) Concatenate(exprs) else exprs.head
      }

    parseAll(expr, input)
  }
```

This code so far is supposed to capture the `type`s (values to be added). But in this form I get the following error:

```
[1.5] failure: `)' expected but `1' found

(typ1: value1) (type2: value2) (type3: value3)
    ^
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have tested, working code that can parse an identifier like `typ1`? It looks to me like the problem is in code that you aren't showing us.